# Recreating SVN repo without a backup

Tags: svn

I had a subversion repository on a CentOS 5 host that was not backed up using the SVN tools and instead wrongly done with rsync.  I'm trying to restore this into a new repository (on a CentOS 6 host - version 1.6.11) but am having some difficulty.

```
# svnadmin verify . 
svnadmin: Can't open file 'format': No such file or directory

# ls
db  hooks  locks
```

and in the db directory are revs (many numbered files) and transactions.

Most of the online directions are based around using the svnadmin dump files, not the raw files that were located inside the repo.

How can I use this non-officially backed up  data to either create a dump, or import into a verifiable repo.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must consider upgrading SVN 1.6.x server to the latest and supported versions (1.9.x or at least 1.8.x as of now). There is no practical reason to use outdated Subversion servers or clients. Moreover, SVN 1.9.x contains numerous improvements compared to 1.6.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have is a regular filesystem backup, there's not a lot you *can* do. You're missing the `conf` directory and `format` file.

First, make sure that you're not operating on your only copy of the repository.

Using the appropriate version of `svnadmin` (matching what you had on the CentOS 5 server), run `svnadmin create tmprepo` in a temporary location. Then copy the `conf` directory and `format` file over to your restored directory, and try `svnadmin verify` again.

This may or may not work, but hopefully it illustrates the importance of preforming backups using the methods outlined in the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  With your pointer, I was able to find the "format" as well as the "conf" directory in the backup, and after editing the "current" file was able to "svnadmin verify" the entire thing.  I have now set up a cron job to do a "svnadmin dump" on the new repo.  Thanks!